# Do I must use .md extension name when I use Markdown syntax in Github?

Tags: github, markdown

I hope to use Markdown syntax for a text file in Github, I find  Markdown syntax is invaild when the file have no extension name.

Do I must use .md extension name when I use Markdown syntax in Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub automatically renders markdown when files end in `.md` or `.markdown` according to [their documentation](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that I must add .md or .markdown extension name for a file in order to use Markdown?

Comment: @HelloCW no extension is treated as plain text so yes you need the extension.